# How to prove the "mollifier" is infinitely differentiable

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, functional-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations

I'm learning Evans' PDEs and noticing the "mollifier" in appendix C, which is:

$$
\eta(x):= \begin{cases}C \exp \left(\frac{1}{|x|^2-1}\right) & \text { if }|x|<1 \\ 0 & \text { if }|x| \geq 1\end{cases}
$$

I'm having difficulties showing that $\eta \in C_0^{\infty}$ even in 1D case. My effort was to establish its arbitrary n-th derivative but result in more crazy thing and no order to follow. I've asked my classmate and he told me to utilize the Taylor's series with integral remainder. Could you please teach me how to prove it?

Comment: Or I'm wondering if there exist a general way to prove a function is infinitely differentiable.

Comment: Hints. Clearly (in the 1D case) all you need is to establish derivatives of all orders at $\pm 1$, the usual rules apply at all other points. So you need to prove by induction something like that just under (1) $\eta^{(n)}(x)$ is a polynomial in $\frac{1}{x-1}$ times the exponential, and at $1$ is $0$. To do this use the usual rules when  $x\ne 1$, and for $x=1$ use the fact that $\lim_{t\to \infty} t^N e^{-t}=0$.